# Where is git reflog expire configuration stored?

Tags: git

I learned that git reflog will expired if the log is older than x days.
The documentation says the default is 90 days. And it says the default got from configuration.

So, I try to check it using

```
git config --global -e
git config --local -e
git config --system -e
```

But there are no configuration for git reflog expire time.

I try to use

```
git reflog expire --expire=180
```

And then check the configurations again, nothing added.

So, where is the configuration of reflog expire time stored? I want to check my reflog expire time.

Comment: Have you tried searching `git help config` for `expire`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill) alludes to, this is set through the [config `gc.reflogExpire`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-gcreflogExpire)

```
gc.reflogExpire
gc.<pattern>.reflogExpire
```

> `git reflog` expire removes reflog entries older than this time; defaults to 90 days.
> The value "`now`" expires all entries immediately, and "`never`" suppresses expiration altogether.
>
> With "`<pattern>`" (e.g. "`refs/stash`") in the middle the setting applies only to the refs that match the `<pattern>`.

For the values, you can use the [`date.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b994622632154fc3b17fb40a38819ad954a5fb88/date.c#L12-L31) and their `approxidate` functions.
(See "**[Working with dates in Git](https://alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git)**" from [**Alex Peattie**](https://twitter.com/alexpeattie))

By default, `git config gc.reflogExpire` would return nothing.

To set it to 180 for all your repos:

```sh
git config --global gc.reflogExpire 180.days.ago
```

To set it to *never* expire:

```sh
git config --global gc.reflogExpire never
```

Although that would not be a recommended best practice: you would usually set it to never expire for a *specific* repository, where you have that particular requirement.

Setting the reflogs to infinity is much more feasible nowadays since computers are way more powerful, so text files with MB or even GB are not that big of a problem. However, an issue which might superseed all those practical benefits is security: if the reflogs are infinite, deleting history with sensitive information will actually never delete anything.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. I read that `gc.reflogExpire` but I don't understand it. Where is `gc.reflogExpire`? I try `git gc.reflogExpire` but failed. I only want to know how to set the expire to 180 days using `git reflog expire --expire=180` (if correct), and how to see the reflog expire time updated to 180 days. So, please give me an example "how to do it".

Comment: @HikkiBocchi Try git config gc.reflogExpire. If it returns nothing, that means it defaults to 90 days. To set it to 180 for all your repos: `git config --global gc.reflogExpire 180`

Comment: Although it defaults to days, it may be clearer to be explicit: `git config --global gc.reflogExpire 180.days.ago`. To set the expiry to 86400 hours (one year): `git config --global gc.reflogExpire 86400.hours.ago`. You can expressions things like `1.month` or `1.year` or `12000.minute` as well.

Comment: (Note that this is all in VonC's link to [Working with dates in Git](https://alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git). The dot syntax, `1.month` instead of `"1 month"`, lets you avoid having to quote things.)

Comment: @torek Good point on using "dot" for the dates. The first approxidate implementation did not have those back in 2005: https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c07b1d19491aa9acb9f8e86486f0b80f976edf9

Comment: Not sure exactly when the dots went in but I remember seeing them in an example early on. Let's see... aha, the dots went in three days later: https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b7b0427728fe31ee2d9375a36f1c27974432979

Comment: How do you do it so it *never* expires?

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro `git config gc.reflogExpire.never` (add `--global` to apply that to all repositories if you need to)

Comment: I think it's with a space maybe? (`git config gc.reflogExpire never`) Anyway, mentioning it would be a nice improvement to your answer.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro I agree. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @VonC, when you mention that you don't recommend it, I assume you do so because the reflog can then become gigantic or are there any other repercussions people might not be aware of? Generally speaking, I think the actual exception nowadays is *not* `never`, since most repos' histories are actually not gigantic, i.e., having reflogs with MBs won't be that much of a problem for today's computing. But, anyway, maybe there are other consequences I'm not aware of.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro No, it is also about security. If you think you have purged your repo from a commit with a sensitive information added by mistake, while reflog never expires... well think again ;)